# "out of stack space" using IE11, angularjs and highcharts-ng plugin

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've found a problem with IE11. When multiple charts was rendered, IE11 throw some "out of stack space" errors.

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/953uLs47/9/) with the code.

After some tests I think the problem is in "[highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)" plugin in this function (row 103):

```
    this.$doCheck = function () {
            if (!detector(ctrl.config, prevConfig)) {
            prevConfig = angular.merge({}, ctrl.config);
            mergedConfig = getMergedOptions($element, ctrl.config, seriesId);

            //Remove any unlinked objects before adding
            this.removeUnlinkedObjects(mergedConfig);

            //Allows dynamic adding Axes
            this.addAnyNewAxes(mergedConfig.yAxis, ctrl.chart, false);
            this.addAnyNewAxes(mergedConfig.xAxis, ctrl.chart, true);

            //Allows dynamic adding of series
            if (mergedConfig.series) {
                // Add any new series
                angular.forEach(ctrl.config.series, function (s) {
                    if (!ctrl.chart.get(s.id)) {
                        ctrl.chart.addSeries(s);
                    }
                });
            }
            ctrl.chart.update(mergedConfig, true);
        }
    };
```

To avoid the problem i've modified the function adding

```
    var is_ie = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
    if ((is_ie) || (ctrl.disableChangeDetection === false)) {
        return;
    }
```

after the first row.

Is possible to fix the problem avoiding my workaround?

Comment: The wrapper which you are using is not an official Highcharts product. Please try to reproduce your case using the official Highcharts angular wrapper https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular and let me know if the problem will still exist.

Comment: I know this isn't the official product but I have not found any other wrappers. The wrapper you suggested me is for Angular and not AngularJS.

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem without the unofficial wrapper (highcharts-ng)? If so, please share the demo. 
If the problem exists only while using the wrapper the good idea would be to create an issue in its Github repo: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: I think the problem is in the unofficial wrapper. With my workaround (bypass $doCheck function), it works.